# One hot encoding of multi label images in keras

Tags: python, pandas, keras, one-hot-encoding, multilabel-classification

I am using PASCAL VOC 2012 dataset for image classification. A few images have multiple labels where as a few of them have single labels as shown below.

```
    0  2007_000027.jpg               {'person'}
    1  2007_000032.jpg  {'aeroplane', 'person'}
    2  2007_000033.jpg            {'aeroplane'}
    3  2007_000039.jpg            {'tvmonitor'}
    4  2007_000042.jpg                {'train'}
```

I want to do one-hot encoding of these labels to train the model. However, I couldn't use keras.utils.to_categorical, as these labels are not integers and pandas.get_dummies is not giving me the results as expected. get_dummies is giving different categories as below, i.e. it is taking each unique combination of labels as one category.

```
 {'aeroplane', 'bus', 'car'}  {'aeroplane', 'bus'}  {'tvmonitor', 'sofa'}  {'tvmonitor'} ...
```

What is the best way to one-hot encode these labels as we don't have specific number of labels for each image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `MultiLabelBinarizer` class allow to do one-hot encoding on multilabel sets, like you have in column `b`:

```
print (df)
                 a                        b
0  2007_000027.jpg               {'person'}
1  2007_000032.jpg  {'aeroplane', 'person'}
2  2007_000033.jpg            {'aeroplane'}
3  2007_000039.jpg            {'tvmonitor'}
4  2007_000042.jpg                {'train'}
```

---

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['b']),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df)
   aeroplane  person  train  tvmonitor
0          0       1      0          0
1          1       1      0          0
2          1       0      0          0
3          0       0      0          1
4          0       0      1          0
```

Or [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) with [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), but it should be slower in large DataFrame:

```
df = df['b'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
print (df)

   aeroplane  person  train  tvmonitor
0          0       1      0          0
1          1       1      0          0
2          1       0      0          0
3          0       0      0          1
4          0       0      1          0
```

Comment: I don't know where I am going wrong, I used MultiLabelBinarizer as you mentioned, But i get the classes like this

   '  ,  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  k  l  m  n  o  p  r  s  t  u  v  w  y  {  }

Comment: @Sree - I know what is problem, there are no sets, but strings, so use `import ast
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` before solutions

Comment: @Sree - Or use `df = df['b'].str.strip("{}").str.get_dummies(', ').rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip("'"))`

Comment: Saved a lot of my time.